# How to Parse text file in python based on condition

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a text file that I want to parse based on the condition that if I find the match phrase in the line then I have to jump to the next line to fetch the value{unfortunately that's how the reports logs are generated}. I have created _dict to check my key and fetch my values in the next line.

```
Lines = f1.readlines()
numlines = len(Lines)
f1.close()
f1 = open('Testlog.txt','r')
f2 =open('writetoFile','r+') 
f3 =open('Results.txt','w')
new_line="Test Name       SubTest         passed      failed         status  "
f3.write(new_line)
f3.write("\n")
while i < numlines:

        line=f1.readline()
        if "Test Name" in line:

            f2.write(line)
            i=i+1
            line =f1.readline()

            if "true" in line:
                f2.write(line)
                line = line.strip('\n ')
                #print line
                data = re.split(r"\s{2,}",line)
                Test_Name=data[4]
                SubTest=data[6]
                passed=data[7]
                failed=data[8]
                status=data[9]
                result = Test_Name + "            " + SubTest + "      " +  passed + "         " + failed + "      "   +  status
                print result 

                f3.write(result)
                f3.write("\n")
                i=i+1
```

I was wondering if there better way to do this

Comment: What exactly is your question? This isn't a code-writing service; if your code isn't working post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and full description of what is wrong with it.

Comment: I am sorry about that I will rephrase the question and attach my sample code

Comment: So does the code not work? What is wrong with it? Could you provide sample inputs and expected and actual outputs? If it does work, and you would like feedback on it, consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com (if you open a question there, again, please do provide sample input data).

Answer (score 0):

What is your method for parsing the line? Can you post sample code, that will help.

To answer your second question, you could make a Dictionary in which each key refers to a List, then you can use a for loop to iterate through each of the values (or whatever you'll need)

```
    foo = { 1 : ['a','b','c'] }

    for value in foo[1]:
        print(value)
```

prints a b c